# Software to play music through two audios systems on two different computers in the same house!

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have two audio systems on two separate computers and I want to be able to play them with the same songs but synchronized and without having any lag. Can you help me with software (Windows 7) that does just that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) to broadcast a scheduled list of media, (audio and video), onto your LAN, see [here](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch05.html), then each computer that you would like to listen on can use either vlc, media player or any player capable of connecting to a network stream to "play" the broadcast.

**NOTE:** They will never be 100% in step due to a number of issues: network rates, buffering, etc., but even if they were if you are a location where you can hear **both** they will *sound* out of step unless you are **exactly** the same distance from both, *due to the speed of sound delays*.

- The server should work on any of Linux, Windows or OS-X
- You should be able to play with any network device that has the capability to consume such streams, i.e. Linux, Windows, OS-X, iOS, Android, RaspberryPi, Internet aware TV or Stereo.
- VLC is free (Gratis and FLOSS)

Answer (score 2):

VLC is probably the best option if you simply play a track or a movie. However, if you want to send any audio to other computers I don't think this can be done with VLC (could anyone confirm or refute?). For that use you might be interested in [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/):

- Windows and Mac
- non-free: 25 USD (noise is overlaid on all transmissions longer than 10 minutes in the free version.)
- Send any audio from your PC to AirPort Express units, Apple TVs, iPhones and iPods Touch, and other PCs and Macs.

[image][image]

Comment: I asked the question there: [Streaming music across your local network with VLC: choosing which application I want to stream the music from?](http://superuser.com/q/828600/116475)